# R compare columns and grep the false values

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean

I have a data frame and first I compare them to create a column of boolean values and then I would like to know which one is false by grep them in the first two columns.

```
df:
    200610-1    200610-10   
AA  AA  TRUE
CC  CC  TRUE
AA  AA  TRUE
AA  EE  FALSE
AA  AA  TRUE
RR  RR  TRUE
AA  AA  TRUE
FF  AA  FALSE
NN  NN  TRUE
AA  AA  TRUE
BB  RR  FALSE

desired output:
4 AA EE
8 FF AA
11 BB RR
```

I compared them by

```
 table(df[,2] == df[,3])
```

But then I don't know how to grep the boolean value into the data frame value. Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't look like an R dataframe. The column names are illegal.

Comment: @42 Well it is theoretically possible to have anything as column names by changing the `colnames` or by creating variables with `df[[somestring]]`. Not that you should though of course!

Comment: But they would not be displayed this way and there would have been three col names.

Comment: @42 Agreed, it was just one pointless remark. I'm guessing the display is due to a copy-paste in stackoverflow. It is possible to have an empty column name also (using "" as string). I am always amazed at how lenient R actually is when it comes to naming stuff. Like the fact that you can name variables with spaces or whatever using `assign`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating the boolean column (I guess in the output we don't need it), just compare the 1st and 2nd compare to create an expression that return the boolean value and use that to subset the rows.

```
df[df[,1]!= df[,2],]
#    200610-1 200610-10
#4        AA        EE
#8        FF        AA
#11       BB        RR
```

Answer (score 1):

Or to use your boolean column:

```
df[which(df[,3]==F),]

4  AA EE FALSE
8  FF AA FALSE
11 BB RR FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are characters, this is yet another way:

```
df[-which(df[,1]==df[,2]),]
```

If you want to use grep, try

```
df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) grepl(x[1], x[2])),]

4  AA EE
8  FF AA
11 BB RR
```